# How to get the Embossed look of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am a newbie to iOS programming. In the app I am writing, I am adding user inputs dynamically/programmatically to UITableView. For each user input, I put it in a UITableViewCell and add it to the UITableView. I want the table cells to look like in the iPhone 'Messages' screen (like a bubble or some embossed look of the 'entire' cell). How is this possible? Any help please?

Comment: check this link http://iphone4developer.blogspot.com/2010/12/creating-sms-bubble-ui-for-chat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this reference...

[Bubble text TableView](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-bubble-ui-iphone-apps)

Hope, this will help you enjoy...